# How do I create a new ApiController with HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that inherits from ApiController, called MyController.

If I create a new one:

new MyController();

It no longer has access to the HttpContext so stuff like:

new MyController().Request

is null.

How can I create a new ApiController with the context intact?

Comment: Does your constructor call the base constructor?

Comment: Yup - I haven't overridden it.

Comment: HttpContext isn't available from the constructor. It is set later in the lifecycle (e.g. it will be available by the time `OnActionExecuting` fires).

Comment: Why are you manually instantiating controllers instead of letting MVC wire them up? There is an `Initialize(RequestContext)` method in `ControllerBase` that sets up those properties for use in `Controller`. This is called when MVC creates controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpContext has nothing to do with Web API, it is a leftover from hosting under ASP.NET runtime.  If you self-host a web api, HttpContext will never be available.

If you are trying to unit test the ApiController then you can simply assign the Request property with a fake request.

If this is a runtime issue, then the Request property will not be set until ExecuteAsync on the ApiController is called by the framework.